# warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow] in Arduino Mega 2560 WI-Fi R3

Tags: arduino

i want to record a long data for like 2 to 3 hours using microcontroller Arduino Mega 2560 WI-FI R3 but I got this warning in my code
below is the picture of the warning i got.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GK3uj.png)

the warning come up when I put the time out constant more than 30000 milliseconds
below is the code I used for the Arduino

```
#include "DHT.h"


// Pin Definitions
#define DHT_PIN_OUT  A1
#define DHTTYPE DHT11
#define MQ3_PIN_OUT A2
#define MQ4_PIN_OUT A3
#define MQ7_PIN_OUT A4



// Global variables and defines

// object initialization
DHT dht(DHT_PIN_OUT, DHTTYPE);


// define vars for testing menu
const int timeout = 180000;       //define timeout of 1 hour
char menuOption = 0;
long time0;

// Setup the essentials for your circuit to work. It runs first every time your circuit is powered with electricity.
void setup() 
{
    // Setup Serial which is useful for debugging
    // Use the Serial Monitor to view printed messages
    Serial.begin(9600);
    while (!Serial) ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB
    Serial.println("start");
    
    dht.begin();
    menuOption = menu();
    
}

// Main logic of your circuit. It defines the interaction between the components you selected. After setup, it runs over and over again, in an eternal loop.
void loop(){  
    if(menuOption == '1') {
      delay(500); //delay 0.5 second
      // DHT11 Humidity and Temperature Sensor 
      // Reading humidity in %
      float dhtHumidity = dht.readHumidity();
      // Read temperature in Celsius, for Fahrenheit use .readTempF()
      float dhtTempC = dht.readTemperature();
      float Alcohol = analogRead(MQ3_PIN_OUT);
      float Methane = analogRead(MQ4_PIN_OUT);
      float CarbonMonoxide = analogRead(MQ7_PIN_OUT);
      Serial.print(F("Humidity: ")); Serial.print(dhtHumidity); Serial.print(F("[%]\t"));
      Serial.print(F("Temp: ")); Serial.print(dhtTempC); Serial.print(F("[C]\t"));
      Serial.print(F("Alcohol: ")); Serial.print(Alcohol); Serial.print(F(" \t"));
      Serial.print(F("Methane: ")); Serial.print(Methane); Serial.print(F(" \t"));
      Serial.print(F("Carbon Monoxide: ")); Serial.println(CarbonMonoxide); Serial.println(F(" \t"));
    }
       
    if (millis() - time0 > timeout){
        menuOption = menu();
    }
}
// Menu function for selecting the components to be tested
// Follow serial monitor for instrcutions
char menu(){

    Serial.println(F("\nSensor Array"));
    Serial.println(F("Press (1) to start the sensor array"));
    while (!Serial.available());

    // Read data from serial monitor if received
    while (Serial.available()){
        char c = Serial.read();
        if (isAlphaNumeric(c)) 
        {   
            
            if(c == '1') 
          Serial.println(F("Now running the sensor array"));
                   else{
                Serial.println(F("illegal input!"));
                menuOption = menu();
                return 0;
            }
            time0 = millis();
            return c;
        }
    }
}
```

sorry for my bad programming and silly question, I'm new to this kind of thing. and I just found out that people usually get answers from StackOverflow, so I just wanted to try asking because I have tried to google the answer but I can't find it.

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/int/

Comment: You'll have more friends, if you show error messages immediately as text. If you remove parts, which don't contribute to the problem.  And if comments fit to the code :) And: One hour are still too many ms for an int on Atmega2560...